# EditText focus not working when second time get focused android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two `EditText`. When these `EditText`s get focused drop-down list will be shown. These drop-down list will be shown at the very first time each `EditText` get focused. And again when the `EditText` get focused, no dropdown is showing.

For example,

First time when `EditText1` is focused drop-down is showing. After that when I select `EditText2` drop down is showing. And again when I select `EditText1`, no drop-down is showing.

My code is,

```
bike_location.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
        } else {
            listViewOEM.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
});
```

What is wrong in my coding? Is there any solution? I have tried a lot.

Comment: If this is a pulldown why not use a spinner ( looks like a combo box ).

Comment: @mjstam : I want to do like this only. Forget about dropdown, take it as toast.

Comment: try putting a `toast` (test) inside the `if(!hasFocus){...}` block. See if the 2nd time you are focusing `EditText1`, whether the `toast` is being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tested your code , it working.
Check your adapter after lost focus ,debug to see your adapter .

Or try to add :  setFocusableInTouchMode

Or refer [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-edittext-listview-loses-focus.html) if your textview in Listview, ExpandedListview